# How to show hosts problems rather than host groups on Zabbix Dashboard?

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

On Zabbix Dashboard there's a Widget called "Problem hosts", which shows a list of host groups rather than a list of hosts.

Is it possible to show problems grouped by hosts instead of grouping them by host groups?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the data as well as triggers that are there for any host then you can use the wiget called Data Overview which provides you all hosts along with any triggers that are present in problem state for that host.